# How to properly use -Exclude in Remove-Item for a list of string from a variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that stored the list of files to be removed in this format:

```
$list = """" + "file1.txt" + """"
```

and a complete `$list` would be looking something like this:

```
$list
"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt",...
```

and trying to use `Remove-Item` with the variable failed, it removed all the files:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Path "c:\myfiles\*" -Exclude $list
```

How to properly achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close but `$list` needs to be an array not a string (with excess quotes).

Just quote each element, and separate them with a comma to do this:

```
$list = "file1.txt","file2.txt"

Remove-Item -Path "c:\myfiles\*" -Recurse -Exclude $list -WhatIf
```

---

I would also recommend reading [about_quoting_rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) as it seems you don't know that double and single quotes do different things.

Using single quotes instead:

```
$list = """" + "file1.txt" + """"
```

can be expressed as:

```
$list = '"file1.txt"'
```

(These extra quotes aren't needed for the code above)